# Javascript on html Canvas element problem

Tags: javascript, debugging, canvas

So I'm trying to create a method where the you move an image around a canvas element.  This is relevant in that in creating many kinds of games, you'd need a background image to move around properly against the canvas and the player's movement.  The problem is that you always draw relative to the canvas's (0,0) point in the top left corner.  So what I'm going for in a conceptualization where pressing right (for example) would be conceived as moving the CANVAS right, when really you're moving the image left.  It could be argued that this is unnecessary, but honestly thinking about it the other way kind of gives me a headache.  I think this way of relating everything to a larger absolute field would be easier to program with a large number of objects.

The problem is, I've messed around with my code in Pycharm but I keep getting canvas not defined and similar errors.  Please help me fix this up!  So without further ado, here's my code! (and any other ways to clean up my code is appreciated, I'm pretty new to JS!)

```
//Animates a moving black dot on the canvas.

//Variables for parameters
var gameloopId;
var speed=6;
var canvas;
var background;
var circle;
var ctx;

//Wait for document to be ready then start
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document is ready');
    init();

});

//Holds the relative coordinates.
function Canvas(){
    this.x=0;//relative X
    this.y=0;//relative Y
    //Calulate screen height and width
    this.width = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("width"));
    this.height = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("height"));
}
canvas=new Canvas();

//Define an object
function Object(){
    this.absX=0;
    this.absY=0;
    this.x=this.absX-canvas.x;
    this.y=this.absY-canvas.y;
}

//Circle Object
function Circle(radius){
    this.radius=radius;
}
Circle.prototype= new Object(); //Circle is an Object
function drawCircle(){
        // Create the circle
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
Background= Image();
Background.prototype=new Object(); //Background is an Object
background= new Background()

function drawBackground(){
        //draw the background
        ctx.drawImage(background,background.x,background.y);
    }

function init(){
    console.log('function init()');
    initSettings();


    //Insert event handler for keyboard movement of circle (space clearInterval)
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode=='37'){    //Left key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.x+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='38'){    //Up key
            circle.absY-=speed;
            canvas.y-=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='39'){    //Right key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.x+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='40'){    //Down key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.y+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='32'){    //Space Bar
            console.log('spacebar');
            clearInterval(gameloopId);
            initSettings();
            gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
        }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode=='37'){
        console.log('left');}//Left key

        if(e.keyCode=='38'){
        console.log('up');}//Up key

        if(e.keyCode=='39'){
        console.log('right');}//Right key

        if(e.keyCode=='40'){
        console.log('down');}//Down key
    });

    //Initialize loop of "game"
    gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
}

function initSettings(){
    console.log('initSettings');

    //Set up canvas
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    //center circle on the horizontal axis
    console.log('setting circle coords');
    circle = new Circle(15);
    circle.x = parseInt(canvas.width/2);
    circle.y = canvas.height - 40;

    //Put background at (0,0)
    background.x=0;
    background.y=0;
    background.src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/back.jpg";
    console.log("background width:"+background.width);
    console.log("background height:"+background.height);
}

function gameLoop(){
    //console.log('function gameLoop()');

    //Has it reached far left side?
    if(circle.x<circle.radius)
    {
        circle.x=circle.radius
    }

    //Has it reached far right side?
    if(circle.x>canvas.width - circle.radius)
    {
        circle.x=canvas.width - circle.radius
    }

    //Has it reached top?
    if(circle.y<circle.radius)
    {
        circle.y=circle.radius
    }

    //has it reached bottom?
    if(circle.y>canvas.height - circle.radius)
    {
        circle.y=canvas.height - circle.radius
    }

    //has background reached left?
    if(background.x < canvas.width-background.width)
    {
        background.x= canvas.width-background.width;
    }

    //has background reached right?
    if(background.x>0)
    {
        background.x=0;
    }

    //has background reached top?
    if(background.y < canvas.height-background.height)
    {
        background.y = canvas.height-background.height;
    }

    //has background reached bottom?
    if(background.y>0)
    {
        background.y=0;
    }

    //Clear the screen (i.e. a draw a clear rectangle the size of the screen)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();

    //draw background
    drawBackground();
    // draw the circle
    drawCircle();


    ctx.restore();

}
```

EDIT:(UPDATED CODE!)

```
//Animates a moving black dot on the canvas.

//Variables for parameters
var gameloopId;
var speed=6;
var canvas;
var background;
var circle;
var ctx;

//Wait for document to be ready then start
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document is ready');
    init();

});

//Holds the relative coordinates.
function Canvas(){
    this.x=0;//relative X
    this.y=0;//relative Y
    //Calulate screen height and width
    this.width = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("width"));
    this.height = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("height"));
}

//Define an object
function MyObject(){
    this.absX=0;
    this.absY=0;
    this.x=this.absX-canvas.x;
    this.y=this.absY-canvas.y;
}

//Circle MyObject
function Circle(radius){
    this.radius=radius;
}
Circle.prototype= new MyObject(); //Circle is an MyObject
function drawCircle(){
        // Create the circle
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
function Background(){
    this.img= Image();
}
Background.prototype=new MyObject(); //Background is an MyObject

function drawBackground(){
        //draw the background
        ctx.drawImage(background,background.x,background.y);
    }

function init(){
    console.log('function init()');
    initSettings();


    //Insert event handler for keyboard movement of circle (space clearInterval)
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode=='37'){    //Left key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.x+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='38'){    //Up key
            circle.absY-=speed;
            canvas.y-=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='39'){    //Right key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.x+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='40'){    //Down key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.y+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='32'){    //Space Bar
            console.log('spacebar');
            clearInterval(gameloopId);
            initSettings();
            gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
        }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode=='37'){
        console.log('left');}//Left key

        if(e.keyCode=='38'){
        console.log('up');}//Up key

        if(e.keyCode=='39'){
        console.log('right');}//Right key

        if(e.keyCode=='40'){
        console.log('down');}//Down key
    });

    //Initialize loop of "game"
    gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
}

function initSettings(){
    console.log('initSettings');

    //Set up canvas
    canvas=new Canvas();
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    //center circle on the horizontal axis
    console.log('setting circle coords');
    circle = new Circle(15);
    circle.x = parseInt(canvas.width/2);
    circle.y = canvas.height - 40;

    //Put background at (0,0)
    background= new Background();
    background.x=0;
    background.y=0;
    background.img.src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/back.jpg";
    console.log("background width:"+background.width);
    console.log("background height:"+background.height);
}

function gameLoop(){
    //console.log('function gameLoop()');

    //Has it reached far left side?
    if(circle.x<circle.radius)
    {
        circle.x=circle.radius
    }

    //Has it reached far right side?
    if(circle.x>canvas.width - circle.radius)
    {
        circle.x=canvas.width - circle.radius
    }

    //Has it reached top?
    if(circle.y<circle.radius)
    {
        circle.y=circle.radius
    }

    //has it reached bottom?
    if(circle.y>canvas.height - circle.radius)
    {
        circle.y=canvas.height - circle.radius
    }

    //has background reached left?
    if(background.x < canvas.width-background.width)
    {
        background.x= canvas.width-background.width;
    }

    //has background reached right?
    if(background.x>0)
    {
        background.x=0;
    }

    //has background reached top?
    if(background.y < canvas.height-background.height)
    {
        background.y = canvas.height-background.height;
    }

    //has background reached bottom?
    if(background.y>0)
    {
        background.y=0;
    }

    //Clear the screen (i.e. a draw a clear rectangle the size of the screen)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();

    //draw background
    drawBackground();
    // draw the circle
    drawCircle();


    ctx.restore();

}



enter code here
```

Comment: Have you looked at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/demos/kitchensink/index.html)? Would make it much easier.

Comment: I'd really like to figure this out with this code... if only so that I figure out WHY this is happening, so I don't make a similar mistake again!  I have a feeling that the problem is pretty basic, since it's showing something as undefined... At the least this is an important learning exercise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  I had a lot of stupid stuff in my ode and lots of bugs - for example background.img is an Image, but all over the place I was trying to get background.width instead of background.img.width.  I also refactored several functions to make things prettier (to em at least).  Thanks to the above for your help!  Here's my "final" code, at least as of right now:

```
//Animates a moving black dot on the canvas.

//Variables for parameters
var gameloopId;
var speed=6;
//var canvas;
var background;
var circle;
var ctx;

//Wait for document to be ready then start
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document is ready');
    init();

});

//Holds the relative coordinates.
var canvas = new function Canvas(){
    this.x=0;//relative X
    this.y=0;//relative Y
    //Calulate screen height and width
    this.width = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("width"));
    this.height = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("height"));
};

//Define an object
function MyObject(){
    this.absX=0;
    this.absY=0;
    this.x=this.absX-canvas.x;
    this.y=this.absY-canvas.y;

    this.updateplace = function (){
        this.x=this.absX-canvas.x;
        this.y=this.absY-canvas.y;
    };
}

//Circle MyObject
function Circle(radius){
    this.radius=radius;
    this.draw=function(){
        // Create the circle
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
Circle.prototype= new MyObject(); //Circle is an MyObject

function Background(){
    this.img= Image();
    this.draw=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(background.img,background.x,background.y);
    }
}
Background.prototype=new MyObject(); //Background is an MyObject

function init(){
    console.log('function init()');
    initSettings();


    //Insert event handler for keyboard movement of circle (space clearInterval)
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode=='37'){    //Left key
            circle.absX-=speed;
            canvas.x-=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='38'){    //Up key
            circle.absY-=speed;
            canvas.y-=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='39'){    //Right key
            circle.absX+=speed;
            canvas.x+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='40'){    //Down key
            circle.absY+=speed;
            canvas.y+=speed;}

        if(e.keyCode=='32'){    //Space Bar
            console.log('spacebar');
            clearInterval(gameloopId);
            initSettings();
            gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
        }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode=='37'){
        console.log('left');}//Left key

        if(e.keyCode=='38'){
        console.log('up');}//Up key

        if(e.keyCode=='39'){
        console.log('right');}//Right key

        if(e.keyCode=='40'){
        console.log('down');}//Down key
    });

    //Initialize loop of "game"
    gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
}

function initSettings(){
    console.log('initSettings');

    //Set up canvas
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("width"));
    canvas.height = parseInt($("#canvas").attr("height"));

    //center circle on the horizontal axis
    console.log('setting circle coords');
    circle = new Circle(15);
    circle.absX = parseInt(canvas.width/2);
    circle.absY = canvas.height - 40;

    //Put background at (0,0)
    background= new Background();
    background.x=0;
    background.y=0;
    background.img.src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/back.jpg";
    console.log("background width:"+background.img.width);
    console.log("background height:"+background.img.height);
    console.log("Right Bound:"+(background.img.width- canvas.width))
}

function gameLoop(){
    //console.log('function gameLoop()');

    //Has it reached far left side?
    if(circle.absX<circle.radius)
    {
        circle.absX=circle.radius
    }

    //Has it reached far right side?

    if(circle.absX>background.img.width - circle.radius)
    {
        circle.absX=background.img.width - circle.radius
    }

    //Has it reached top?
    if(circle.absY<circle.radius)
    {
        circle.absY=circle.radius
    }

    //has it reached bottom?
    if(circle.absY>background.img.height - circle.radius)
    {
        circle.absY=background.img.height - circle.radius
    }

    //has canvas reached right bound?
    if(canvas.x > background.img.width- canvas.width)
    {
        canvas.x= background.img.width- canvas.width;
    }

    //has canvas reached left bound?
    if(canvas.x<0)
    {
        canvas.x=0;
    }

    //has background reached bottom bound?
    if(canvas.y > background.img.height - canvas.height)
    {
        canvas.y = background.img.height - canvas.height;
    }

    //has background reached top bound?
    if(canvas.y<0)
    {
        canvas.y=0;
    }

    //Clear the screen (i.e. a draw a clear rectangle the size of the screen)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();

    //draw background
    background.updateplace();
    background.draw();
    // draw the circle
    circle.updateplace();
    circle.draw();


    ctx.restore();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't think you can write your own `Object`</strike> You definitely can't use `Object`, it's a [reserved keyword](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm). Object is the built in javascript object that all objects inherit from. You have basically overwritten it. That could be your problem.

Try calling it `myObject` to check if this is the problem.

```
//Define an myObject
function myObject(){
    this.absX=0;
    this.absY=0;
    this.x=this.absX-canvas.x;
    this.y=this.absY-canvas.y;
}

Circle.prototype= new myObject(); //Circle is a myObject
```

Comment: Well, I'm almost certain that that was one problem.  But I'm also having a problem where background is undefined (background.x=0)  Firebug also tells me something about converting WrappedNative to Function...

Comment: you have changed `Background.prototype=new Object();` to `Background.prototype=new myOject();` haven't you?

Comment: Yes, I refactored all usages of Object() to MyObject()

Comment: In any case though thank you - even if overwriting the Object constructor wasn't the problem, something stupid like that would have eventually led to SOME kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Background= Image();
Background.prototype=new Object(); //Background is an Object
background= new Background()
```

seems suspicious.
edit : Background is an Element. You add a prototype even though it is not a function.
Then you call Background as a constructor but it is not.

So background is likely to be undefined. I am surprised background.x gives you 0.
By the way, you should `parseInt(arg, 10)` to get your result in decimal and not octal.

Comment: the background.x=0 is part of my code, the place where the error is being shown.  I refactored this and now am having trouble with the canvas.width and canvas.height elements - I'll post an edit with the new code.